# How to test a model for file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, file-upload, upload, rspec

I have a model where I use the method to upload images

In Image controller I call
DataFile.save_image_file(params[:upload])

My code data_file.rb

```
      def self.save_image_file(upload)
        file_name = upload['datafile'].original_filename  if  (upload['datafile'] !='')    
        file = upload['datafile'].read    

        file_type = file_name.split('.').last
        new_name_file = Time.now.to_i
        name_folder = new_name_file
        new_file_name_with_type = "#{new_name_file}." + file_type
        new_file_name_thumb_with_type = "#{new_name_file}-thumb." + file_type

        image_root = "#{RAILS_CAR_IMAGES}"


          Dir.mkdir(image_root + "#{name_folder}");
          File.open(image_root + "#{name_folder}/" + new_file_name_with_type, "wb")  do |f|  
            f.write(file)
          end

[new_name_file, new_file_name_with_type, new_file_name_thumb_with_type]

      end
```

I want to test it in RSpec

data_file_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DataFile do
  describe "Should save image file" do 


    before(:each) do
      @file = fixture_file_upload('/files/test-bus-1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    end

    it "Creating new car name and thumb name" do
      @get_array = save_file(@file)
      @get_array[:new_name_file].should_not be_nil
    end

  end
end
```

But test doesn't work

Failure/Error: @file = fixture_file_upload('/files/test-bus-1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `fixture_file_upload' for #

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess`. Try something like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DataFile do
  describe "Should save image file" do 
    let(:file) do
      extend ActionDispatch::TestProcess
      fixture_file_upload('/files/test-bus-1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    end

    it "Creating new car name and thumb name" do
      @get_array = save_file(file)
      @get_array[:new_name_file].should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: File is perceived, but the method does not see another property loader - upload ['datafile']

Comment: In view i use <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>&nbsp;<%= submit_tag t('field.upload_file') %><br/>

Comment: Worked - DataFile.save_image_file(params[:upload][:datafile], params[:car_id])